# loadPreference() for preferenceActivity method throws exception first time app is installed

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am a newbie to android, so please be patient.
I am trying to learn preferences. I have an app that has a `mainActivity`, when the menu icon it's pressed a `MyPreferenceActivity` is shown. It allows the user setting some preferences related to a subject. 
In my `mainActivity` I have a `loadPrefernces` method that works fine when the app is installed, but the first time it throws an error: `unable to start activity component info[..] java.lang.NullPointerException`
Here is my code:
`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String PREFERENCE_FILENAME = "com.id11298775.exercise6_preferences";
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadPreferences(); // this cause the error
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyPreferenceActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadPreferences();

}

private void loadPreferences() {

    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILENAME,
            MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Setting the textView related to the subject
        TextView subjectTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activitymain_favouritesubjectresult_tv);
        subjectTv.setText(mSharedPreferences.getString("list_subject_pref",
                null));
        // Setting the TextView related to the URL
        TextView urlTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activitymain_handbookurlresult_tv);
        urlTv.setText(mSharedPreferences.getString("et_subject_pref", null));
        // Setting the TextView related to the times selected
        TextView labTimeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activitymain_labtimeresult_tv);
        // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, ?> map = mSharedPreferences.getAll();
        Object cs = map.get("list_times_pref");
        labTimeTv.setText(cs.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

this is my `MyPreferenceActivity`

```
public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {

    if (key.equals("list_subject_pref")) {
        ListPreference preference = (ListPreference) findPreference(key);
        CharSequence currText = preference.getEntry();
        preference.setSummary(currText);
    } else if (key.equals("et_subject_pref")) {
        EditTextPreference preference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(key);
        String newUrl = preference.getText().toString();
        preference.setSummary(newUrl);
    } else if (key.equals("list_times_pref")) {
        Set<String> selections = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(
                "list_times_pref", null);
        String[] selected = selections.toArray(new String[] {});
        String listSelection = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
            listSelection += selected[i] + " ";

        }
        MultiSelectListPreference multi = (MultiSelectListPreference) findPreference(key);
        multi.setSummary(listSelection);
    } else if (key.equals("ringtonePref")) {

    RingtonePreference preference = (RingtonePreference) findPreference("ringtonePref");

        String strRingtonePreference = ((SharedPreferences) preference).getString("ringtonePref", "none");
        Uri ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(strRingtonePreference);
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri);
        String name = ringtone.getTitle(this);
        preference.setSummary("select " + name);
    }

}

}
```

here is logcat:
[image]

I think that the first time the app is installed there are no preference set, therefore the error, but I can't figure out a good way to prevent the exception.
Anybody can please help me?

Comment: Please post your entire logcat also.

Comment: @Rahil2952 is that fine or you prefer a text file?

Comment: What is on line 67 in your MainActivity?

Comment: line 66: Map<String, ?> map = mSharedPreferences.getAll();
line 67: Object cs = map.get("list_times_pref");

Comment: I think you should define default SharedPreference values so first time it sets them as a value and won't give you exception.

Comment: How should I do that?